# What is wrong with this MySQL query in C#?

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to insert multiple rows into a table by building a query by iterating through a list. I'm getting errors for my SQL syntax, it looks like this:

```
            string sql = "insert into achievement(Rank,Event,UserId) values ";
            string valueSQL = "";



            using (command = new MySqlCommand("begin;" +
                " insert into profile(Username,TextInfo) values(@username,@textinfo);" +
                " set @userid = LAST_INSERT_ID(); " +
                  sql +
                " insert into social(URL,UserId) values(@url,@userid);" +
                " COMMIT;", conn))
            {

                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("username", dto.Username);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("textinfo", dto.FreeText);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("url", dto.SocialURL);

                for(int i = 0; i < dto.achievementDTOs.Count; i++)
                {
                    valueSQL += /*(valueSQL == "" ? "": ",") +*/ "(@rank" + i + ",@event" + i + ",@userid)";
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("rank"+i, dto.achievementDTOs[i].Rank);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("event"+i, dto.achievementDTOs[i].Event);
                }
                sql += valueSQL;
                sql += ";";

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The end results of building this query should look something like this:

```
"begin;" +
            " insert into profile(Username,TextInfo) values(@username,@textinfo);" +
            " set @userid = LAST_INSERT_ID(); " +
            " insert into achievement(Rank,Event,UserId) values (@rank0,@event0,@userid) (@rank1,@event1,@userid)" etc. etc. etc. +
            " insert into social(URL,UserId) values(@url,@userid);" +
            " COMMIT;"
```

Comment: You try to execute multiple queries at once. That  won't work.

Comment: The error message returned should be a good place to look

Comment: @juergend I can run multiple queries using begin; and COMMIT; it has worked before when I hardcoded the query instead of building it.

Comment: @BugFinder The error message marks the entire query as syntax error and doesn't specify anything

Comment: @iAgonyii normally it says something like "Syntax error near ..something.."

Comment: Event is listed between the reserved keywords. Add backticks around it.

Comment: Also that _valueSQL_ could result in invalid syntax if you have two record to insert. There is no separator between the blocks added

Answer (score 1):

Ive seen the problem

Your code:

```
 string sql = "insert into achievement(Rank,Event,UserId) values ";
            string valueSQL = "";

        using (command = new MySqlCommand("begin;" +
            " insert into profile(Username,TextInfo) values(@username,@textinfo);" +
            " set @userid = LAST_INSERT_ID(); " +
              sql +
            " insert into social(URL,UserId) values(@url,@userid);" +
            " COMMIT;", conn)
```

So. look carefully, at the sql string.. you didnt add the values to insert..  the syntax error would have pointed this out. I havent tried adding multiple rows in one insert like that, but, if that is valid, form the sql as you have but only after working out the sql variale.. eg more like

```
 string sql = "insert into achievement(Rank,Event,UserId) values ";
            string valueSQL = "";

                for(int i = 0; i < dto.achievementDTOs.Count; i++)
            {
                valueSQL += /*(valueSQL == "" ? "": ",") +*/ "(@rank" + i + ",@event" + i + ",@userid)";
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("rank"+i, dto.achievementDTOs[i].Rank);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("event"+i, dto.achievementDTOs[i].Event);
            }
            sql += valueSQL;
            sql += ";";

            using (command = new MySqlCommand("begin;" +
                " insert into profile(Username,TextInfo) values(@username,@textinfo);" +
                " set @userid = LAST_INSERT_ID(); " +
                  sql
                " insert into social(URL,UserId) values(@url,@userid);" +
                " COMMIT;", conn)
```